# Using Laplace equations to solve a heat problem . (PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

One edge of the square plate with insulated faces is kept at uniform temperature $u_{0}$ and the other three edges are kept at temperature zero. Without solving a boundary value problem, but by superposition of solutions of like problems to obtain the trivial case in which all four edges are at temperature $U_{0}$ show why the steady temperature at the center of the given plate must be $U_{0}/4$

What i tried

Laplace equation of a PDE with four edges have the boundary conditions of the form

$$u(0,y)=g_{1}(y)$$
$$u(L,y)=g_{2}(y)$$
$$u(x,0)=f_{1}(x)$$
$$u(x,H)=f_{2}(x)$$

But all the boundary conditions here are non-homogenous, to get a homogeneous boundary conditions in order to solve the PDE we must split the solution into four parts and the add up the solutions of the four parts after solving each individually with the boundary conditions of each part being homogeneous  (This can be done due to the linearity property). An example of the boundary conditions for one part is given below.

$$u(0,y)=0$$
$$u(L,y)=g_{2}(y)$$
$$u(x,0)=f_{1}(x)$$
$$u(x,H)=f_{2}(x)$$

Is my explnation correct and could it be improved upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one plate at $u_0$, let the temperature at the center be $T$.

Because it is a square, by symmetry, the temperature will also be $T$ when one of the other three plates is at $u_0$.

By linearity, the four solutions added together will be the solution for the case that all four plates are at $u_0$.

But in this case, the solution is trivial, which is a constant $u_0$ at all points, including the center in particular.

Hence we have
$$4T=u_0$$